# Data transfers between data sets

Tags: r

There are countries and continental information for covid-19 cases in the df database.

The df8 dataset contains population information.

df1 also addressed yesterday to reach the country's new case count.

In df4, I have printed the total deaths so far as continents.

I also found population information of continents.

my problem is to separate the data of new cases (yesterday's death) into continents. proportion to the population written in df8.

```
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
 timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

yesterday <- function() Sys.Date() - 1L
yesterday()
df1 <- aggregate(death ~ countryName, subset(df, day == yesterday()), sum)
df8 <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hirenvadher954/Worldometers-                      
     Scraping/master/countries.csv',
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 df4 <- aggregate(death ~ region, subset(df), sum)


  library(tidyverse)

      df %>% 
      left_join(df8, by = c("countryName" = "country_name")) %>% 
      mutate(population = as.numeric(str_remove_all(population, ","))) %>% 
      group_by(countryName) %>%
      slice(1) %>%
      group_by(region) %>% 
      summarize(population = sum(population, na.rm = TRUE))
```

There are countries and continental information for covid-19 cases in the df database.

The df8 dataset contains population information.

df1 also addressed yesterday to reach the country's new case count.

In df4, I have printed the total deaths so far as continents.

I also found population information of continents.

my problem is to separate the data of new cases (yesterday's death) into continents. proportion to the population written in df8.

so as output

region    death    population   rate

africa   234      523452656    86/44545

americas     24562    4123548621   15/4453284
.
.
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your expected values are way off.  For example the population of the Americas is about [1 billion people](https://www.google.com/search?q=population%20of%20the%20americas&oq=population%20of%20the%20americas&aqs=chrome..69i57j46j0l6.7055j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), not 4 billion.  Africa is also about [1.2 billion](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ALeKk01ZFB8BH4R-CcBj1DblLdATeeQ7ag%3A1588696026854&ei=2pOxXo7AM5vctAa94rHIBg&q=population%20of%20africa&oq=population%20of%20afr&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgkIABBDEEYQ-wEyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BAgAEEc6BAgAEEM6BAgAEApQza8IWIK5CGCSkg1oAXACeAGAAcECiAHTBZIBBzIuMi4wLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab), not 5 billion.

```
df %>% 
  left_join(df8, by = c("countryName" = "country_name")) %>% 
  mutate(population = as.numeric(str_remove_all(population, ","))) %>% 
  group_by(countryName) %>% 
  filter(day == yesterday()) %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  summarize(population = sum(population, na.rm = TRUE),
            death = sum(death, na.rm = TRUE),
            prop = paste0(as.character(death), "/", as.character(population)))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  region   population  death prop            
  <chr>         <dbl>  <int> <chr>           
1 Africa   1304908713   1842 1842/1304908713 
2 Americas 1019607512  87805 87805/1019607512
3 Asia     4601849172  20027 20027/4601849172
4 Europe    738083720 142158 142158/738083720
5 Oceania    40731992    115 115/40731992
```